# xml to json, is there a way to use an attribute's value as a key for easier lookup?

Tags: node.js, xml-parsing

I have an XML file containing multiple items and I tried a couple of xml to json libray and settled on csv-parser.
right now if I want to check if the object meet the requirement I want before transforming it, I need to loop through the items, and then loop through the property tag to see if I can find the property DisplayType and then check it's value.

Is there a way to tell csv-parser to use the "name" attribute as an ID for the object?

Sometimes I have 5 for-loops in each other and it's getting confusing.

EDIT:
The main goal is to filter the items where the value for **property[@name='DisplayType']** is **Weapon**, loop through those and do some stuff. Then rince and repeat for other properties and attributes.

I need to filter, arrange and add data before inserting in a database.

"Raw":

```
<items>
    <item name="Knife">
        <property name="HoldType" value="31"/>
        <property name="DisplayType" value="Weapon"/>
        <property name="Meshfile" value="Items/Misc/parcelPrefab"/>
        <property name="Material" value="MresourceCrop"/>
        <property name="Stack" value="10"/> 
        <property name="Value" value="3"/>
        <events>
                <event name="Testing Events" type="Something"/>
                <event name="Testing Events2" type="Something"/>
        </events>
    </item>
    <item name="Knife">
        <property name="HoldType" value="31"/>
        <property name="DisplayType" value="Weapon"/>
        <property name="Meshfile" value="Items/Misc/parcelPrefab"/>
        <property name="Material" value="MresourceCrop"/>
        <property name="Stack" value="10"/> 
        <property name="Value" value="3"/>
    </item>
</items>
```

Json (example):

```
{
    "items": {
        "item": [
            {
                "name": "Knife",
                "property": [
                    {
                        "name": "HoldType",
                        "value": "31"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "DisplayType",
                        "value": "Weapon"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Meshfile",
                        "value": "Items/Misc/parcelPrefab"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Material",
                        "value": "MresourceCrop"
                    },
```

What I wish I could get:

```
{
    "items": {
            "Knife": {
                "name": "Knife",
                "property": [
                    "HoldType": {
                        "name": "HoldType",
                        "value": "31"
                    },
                    "DisplayType": {
                        "name": "DisplayType",
                        "value": "Weapon"
                    },
                    "Meshfile": {
                        "name": "Meshfile",
                        "value": "Items/Misc/parcelPrefab"
                    },
                    "Material": {
                        "name": "Material",
                        "value": "MresourceCrop"
                    },
```

Comment: Do you HAVE to convert your xml to JSON or can you use something like xpath on the original?

Comment: @JackFleeting Ohh this library didn't show up in my searches! I'll give it a try, it must be easier than to deal with freaking JSON :P If you want to make a quick answer with how to query the XML file, I'll mark as answered.

Comment: Is your desired output in this case the word `weapon`?

Comment: Yes I want to be able to fetch the items where DisplayType == Weapon. I'm playing with the library right now, but I'm reading the source code right now trying to figure out how it works.

Comment: Just to be clear - in your example `DisplayType` does not `== Weapon`; the two relevant nodes are`property` and each has a `name` attribute with the value `DisplayType` AND a `value` attribute with the value `Weapon`. That's what distinguishes those two nodes from the others which have the same name and attributes, but different attribute values. So  are looking to select these two nodes?

Comment: Yes sorry, that is what I have a lot of issues with. I want a list of "Item" where `property[@name='DisplayType'] = @value['Weapon']` if that makes sense. The goal is to transform the XML file to be imported in a database and depending on the values I need to add some extra information. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```js
const { transform } = require('camaro')

;(async function () {
    const xml = `
    <items>
        <item name="Knife">
            <property name="HoldType" value="31"/>
            <property name="DisplayType" value="Weapon"/>
            <property name="Meshfile" value="Items/Misc/parcelPrefab"/>
            <property name="Material" value="MresourceCrop"/>
            <property name="Stack" value="10"/> 
            <property name="Value" value="3"/>
            <events>
                    <event name="Testing Events" type="Something"/>
                    <event name="Testing Events2" type="Something"/>
            </events>
        </item>
        <item name="Knife">
            <property name="HoldType" value="31"/>
            <property name="DisplayType" value="Weapon"/>
            <property name="Meshfile" value="Items/Misc/parcelPrefab"/>
            <property name="Material" value="MresourceCrop"/>
            <property name="Stack" value="10"/> 
            <property name="Value" value="3"/>
        </item>
    </items>
    `

    const template = {
        items: {
            Knife: ['/items/item[@name="Knife"]', {
                Name: '@name',
                HoldType: 'property[@name="HoldType"]/@value',
                DisplayType: 'property[@name="DisplayType"]/@value',
                Meshfile: 'property[@name="Meshfile"]/@value',
                Material: 'property[@name="Material"]/@value',
                Stack: 'property[@name="Stack"]/@value',
                Value: 'property[@name="Value"]/@value',
            }]
        }
    }

    const result = await transform(xml, template)

    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
})()
```

Output

[image]

Comment: I love this solution! It's clear and easy. Thanks for that!! <3

Answer (score 1):

The xpath expression

```
/items/item/property[@name="DisplayType"][@value="Weapon"]
```

or its equivalent

```
/items/item/property[@name="DisplayType" and @value="Weapon"]
```

will select the two nodes in your example with the desired attribute values.

Comment: Thanks, can I get the parent of that? Right now it return 15 results, all the same lines :P I tried `/parent::store` at the end, like the specs, but I guess the library have another way of doing it.

Comment: Nm, `//items/item/property[@name="DisplayType"][@value="Weapon"]/parent::item` :) Thanks for getting me started with this.

Comment: @HypeWolf - In your xml there is no `store`; the parent of each of these two nodes is `item` with a `name` attribute whose attribute value is `Knife` and the grandparent is `items`.with no attributes.

Comment: Yea I made the mistake of not reading and copy/pasting... I don't know what's going on today. :P